# Kafka conditional serialization from application.properties

Tags: java, json, spring, serialization, apache-kafka

I have a dto I send from Kafka producer.
Dto in separate module, which don't contain any spring dependencies, just lombok.

```
@Data
public class ProductDto implements Serializable {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String title;
    private String price;
    private String quantity;

}
```

I have custom property for field.

```
#serialize field or not
kafka.model.product.fields.title.enabled=true
```

I would like to perform a custom serialization with conditional on property from `application.properties`.
I would like to make a flexible approach where I can make fast changes in another class without AOP and reflection

I send this dto in main module, which include dto module.

```
public void sendProductEvent(String key, ProductDto product) {
    log.info("productEvent", product);
    kafkaTemplate.send("productTopic", key, eventMapper.toEvent(product));
}
```

I was going to do it using

```
@Value("${kafka.model.product.fields.title.enabled}")
```

inside of

```
@JsonIgnore(value = "${kafka.model.product.fields.title.enabled}")
```

Something like this. But as I described, dto from another module, it doesn't have any spring dependencies, just lombok.

I can use `@Value` or `@ConfigurationProperties` only in main module, where I have logic.